# Python Pandas, Boolean Indexing: How to select all rows with a "True" value

Tags: python, indexing, boolean

let's assume I need a "starting pont" of a filter. How can I get a boolean index of all values in a column to be 'True'?

Minimal example:
-> Obvious. If I have a df of shape (2, 2) I'd like to get a boolean index of (2,1) = True. Of course the 2 rows is variable and the amount of columns as well.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

now I have a condition like "the value in col1 needs to be 1", so I do:

```
boolean_index = df.loc[:,'col1']==1
```

which returns

```
0     True
1    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

But what I want is to NOT SPECIFY ANY CONDITION (e.g. not specify boolean_index = df.loc[:,'col1']**==1**) and return

```
0     True
1     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

I probably I'm just to stupid to figure it out? Or did nobody ask this question?

Comment: Interesting that people downvote on such an obvious question. But yes, here's the minmal exapmple:

import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

the boolean index should be e.g. index:[True, True] as there has not been any selection added yet.

Comment: "a boolean index of all values" is that every row is set on true (the selection is <select all rows>)

Comment: interesting approach. However, the return contains 4 rows instead of two :(
    pd.Series([True]*df.size, name='col1')

    0    True
    1    True
    2    True
    3    True
   Name: col1, dtype: bool

Comment: Yes, my bad. Surely you know how to get the number of rows in `df` and fix it.

Comment: pd.Series([True]*df.shape[0], name='col1') smells a bit... ain't it?

Comment: What is the problem? TBH I do not even understand why you are asking a question at all. What is hard about creating a boolean `Series` with a specific shape and name (and index, if you want that too) and setting all values to `True`?

Comment: BTW the expected output accordig to the question is a boolean `Series` not a boolean `Index`.

Comment: @Goyo I think you should post it as a solution, so that I can (positively) vote on it. I'm happy to explain why I am asking the question at all. However, I've been in AppDev for multiple years and I know it is a hack.

Comment: It this really what you are after? It looks to me that you would have done it by yourself if it were. Plus you suggested it is smelly and, IIUC, hackish. I do not think this is the answer you need. But I don't know why.

Comment: I do actually have the feeling that you all found a bug.... @goyo

Comment: I do actually have the feeling that you all found a bug.... @dhjc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely clear what you are after, but to get a column of True that you can filter on:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col' : ['Something'] * 300})
df['FilterCol'] = df.Col.apply(lambda x : x == 'Something')
```

Then:

```
df[df['FilterCol']]
```

Returns everything.  Change 'Something' for 'Nothing' (or anything else, obviously) in the lambda function, and it is empty.

Then you can just change the lambda function based on what you want to filter on.

(Edit - based on example now in question - add:

```
df.apply(lambda x : True)
```

to the end of your code to get the answer you are looking for.)

(Edit 2 - from new minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.apply(lambda x : True, axis=1)
```

Output is:

```
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Which doesn't state the name as well as the dtype as in your example, but that's as far as I know how to get to.

(Final edit (hopefully :) )

```
df.col1.apply(lambda x : True)
```

Outputs the answer I think you are looking for. )